# php 5.3 and libxml2 nightmare

Tags: php, centos5, yum, update

My CentOS 5.7 ships with libxml2 2.6.26 that is very outdated and also causes many problems with my current PHP 5.3.3. I need to update libxml2 to 2.7.8 version or at least 2.7.3+ i've readed many posts, used google to find a solution but i'm really unable to solve this issue that is driving me nuts. So please, if there is anyone who knows how to upgrade this library without breaking the OS, please, help me. I need a secure and confirmed answer.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd be best served by upgrading to CentOS 6.2?  It would at this time get PHP 5.3.3 and libxml2 2.7.6 from the usual repositories.

Comment: One of the strengths of CentOS is that it _doesn't_ change quickly.  But the corollary to this is that cutting-edge versions of software will not be automatically available.  Of course, you're always free to compile from source into some new, separate directory.

Comment: I can't upgrade to 6.2. CentOS is not upgradable, so i would need to install it from scratch. I need a solution to install that library only, i can't believe that it could be so dificult...

Answer (score 0):

@FidoBoy If you mean you're unable to upgrade CentOS, you can post eh error/message here and someone will assist.

Else, you can upgrade CentOS through yum,

```
yum upgrade
```

Additionally, compiling and installing Libxml 2.7.x version is very much possible. However, you need to make sure that you install the latest version in a separate directory by providing the --prefix option. You will also need to then recompile PHP and provide the path of the libxml 2.7.x library so that it will use the latest and not the one present in the lib directories.

Comment: I'm afraid that i'm not an expert when mantaining a linux server, cause i'm mainly a programmer. However i'm into a library dependencies nightmare and i can find an easy way to escape from it. My system is running CentOS 5.7 with Plesk panel 10.4.4. Using the Plesk repos i've upgraded PHP into PHP53 (php 5.3.3) but this causes a serious problems and bugs with libxml2 (if you use DOMDocument it has many bugs).

Comment: So i think that the easiest way to solve my situation is to install an updated libxml2 into the CentOS system. I didn't knew that i'll need to recompile PHP to do this... this is very annoying cause PHP is installed by plesk and i'm afraid that recompile it could be very difficult.

Comment: So, sincerely i need some advice tips about the best way to go and to solve this situation. I can't believe that CentOS doesn't provide an easy way to run PHP 5.3.x. As i've readed on the CentOS website, installing packages compiling from sources is not recommended and it could be better to install it using yum